PHP date from MySQL format to swedish month. Error DateTimeInterface
I have a row coming from mysql query like this:
$date=$row['date'];

In MySQL this date is stored like this:
2024-12-28 (Y-m-d)

I want to display this date in Swedish language like this:
28 Maj 2024

I am trying it like this:
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'sv_SE');
$date=$row['date'];
echo date_format($date,"d M Y");

But I get error DateTimeInterface, any idea how to achieve this?

What is the exact error message? There is no DateTime object in use.

Are you sure your problem is in any way directly related to MySQL or HTML? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Are you sure, $date is already an object?
You need to parse it first. Also date_format can not handle internationalization, you have to use IntlDateFormatter:
$row['date'] = '2024-5-28';

$cal = IntlCalendar::fromDateTime($row['date']);
echo IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($cal, "d MMMM Y", 'sv_SE');

will print
28 maj 2024

see the fiddle here: https://3v4l.org/NWRBj
